# Is IIS running x64 or x86 for Azure Cloud Services?

Tags: c#, c++, iis, azure

I am trying to run some native c++ code in my website deployed with Azure Cloud Services and I am facing some BadImageFormatException.

I have manage to the dll loaded and running in the WebRole itself but when hitting the website the YSOD is thrown with exceptions that it could not load my DLL.

The native code is build against x64 and I speculate in this being the problem. I need the native code to be x64. Is this not supported for IIS or can I do something related to the cloud service to tell IIS to use 64 bit?

I tried using DependencyWalker to see if I could figure out which dependency that was missing and it flagged the following with a question mark. If that means anything to anyone.

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL   
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a 64 bit only environment,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh694038.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haniatassi/archive/2009/03/20/using-a-32bit-dll-in-the-windows-azure.aspx

So when you meet `BadImageFormatException` it needs to be further investigated on which library's bitness is wrong.

The strange items showed in DependencyWalker are private things Microsoft uses during Windows source code compilation, and usually you can safely ignore them.

Comment: sorry, you didnt read "cloud services". I dont care about azure websites. Webroles get their own VM.

Comment: Just edited, and it seems that Web Roles are running in full 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks. Thats where I am at now, trying to investigate why it fails. The funny thing is that it actually is able to run within the WebRole itself but not when used in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter IIS settings by calling simple script with the startup tasks.

Add a `setup.cmd` file in the solution containing these:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.enable32BitAppOnWin64:true

     exit /b 0
```

Set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always` for this file.

Add these xml to your ServiceDefinition.csdef file.

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="setup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
</Startup>
```

When you deploy again, IIS will be configured to run in 32bit.